# whats wrong with my this php code snippet

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","*******","******");
if (!$connection) {
die('PHP Mysql database connection could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
}
else{ 
$db_name = "*****";
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM subscribers WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['email']!=""){
if ($num_rows > 0) {
echo "email already unsubscribed";
}
else {
$update_sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '1' WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
mysql_query($update_sql, $connection);
echo "<div id='notify' style ='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 330px; height: 40px; text-align: center;  background-color: #9BFFCD; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; padding-top:18px; border: solid #060 thin;'> YOU'RE UNSUBSCRIBED</div>";
}

}
}
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Unsubscribe Page</title>
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('notify').style.display = 'none';
    /* or
    var item = document.getElementById('notify')
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item); 
    */
  }, 3000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 330px; height: 80px; text-align: center; margin-top:100px;">
<div style="height: 30px; margin-bottom: 12px; padding-top: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; background-color:#FBDACE"><strong>CONFIRM UR EMAIL-ID BELOW TO UNSUBSCRIBE</strong><span style="text-align: center"></span></div>
<div style="height: 30px; margin-bottom: 12px; padding-top: 9px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; background-color:#FBDACE">
<form method="post" name="update" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" size="33" /></td>
      <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Unsubscribe" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

What I want is when user enters his email id then if it is already exists in table record then it shows an echo message already unsubscribed, otherwise it unsubscribe the user on unsubscribe button click

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How-to-create-a-Minimal-Complete-and-Verifiable-example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) "_

Comment: what is it doing wrong now? It appears to me the logic is the wrong way around. Your checking if you have an existing email and then if you have it you say you are already unsubscribed, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: i want to check with select query that if the entered email id exists in the table if yes then it shows the message "you're already unsubscribed" else if user email id doesn't exists in table then record updated using update query and then it shows the message "you're unsusbscribed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM subscribers WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['email']!=""){
if ($num_rows > 0) {
echo "email already unsubscribed";
}
else {
$update_sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '1' WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
mysql_query($update_sql, $connection);
echo "<div id='notify' style ='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 330px; height: 40px; text-align: center;  background-color: #9BFFCD; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; padding-top:18px; border: solid #060 thin;'> YOU'RE UNSUBSCRIBED</div>";
}
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['email']!=""){
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM subscribers WHERE 
      email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND unsubscribed ='1'";);
       $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
       if ($num_rows > 0) {
         echo "email already unsubscribed";
       }
      else {
  $update_sql = "UPDATE subscribers SET unsubscribed = '1' WHERE 
  email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
  mysql_query($update_sql, $connection);
  echo "<div id='notify' style ='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 330px; height: 40px; text-align: center;  background-color: #9BFFCD; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; padding-top:18px; border: solid #060 thin;'> YOU'RE UNSUBSCRIBED</div>";
}
```

Changes :

1. SELECT query is executed after checking whether the FORM has been POSTed and email field is not empty.
2. Added unsubscribed = '1' clause in SELECT query otherwise it will fetch records which are not yet unsubscribed.

Comment: after changing to your code, the page is showing nothing

Comment: hmmm... that means during copy-paste something was wrongly copied. can you turn on error reporting to see the cause of the error.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

2. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors